# Stripe checkout form - Index of forms on the page - Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, stripe-payments

After playing with my code whilst a little too tired I accidently deleted a perfectly working stripe checkout form on my invoice index page. After putting the pieces back together I seem to be stuck at a problem I didn't have before...

I have an index of user invoices that lists each invoice in a loop and then amongst other things, presents an option for the user to pay the invoice on the index page using Stripe Checkout popup payment form.

```
  <% @user.invoices.where(payment_status: false).find_each do |invoice| %>

        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
          <p>Details</p>
          <%= link_to "View Details", invoice_path(invoice,user_id: current_user.id) %>
          <%= form_tag invoice_pay_path(invoice), method: :patch, value: 1 do %>
            <%=link_to "Pay Invoice", '#', class:"btn btn-success pay_button"%>
          <% end%>
        </div>
```

I have used in-line script so as to be able to use the invoice variable from the loop:

```
<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: $('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'),
image: "<%= image_path "half logo.png"%>",
locale: 'auto',
token: function(token) {
  // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
  // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  var token = token.id;
  //Inject the card token in a hidden field.
  theForm.append( $('<input type="hidden" name="stripe_card_token">').val(token) );
  //Submit form to our Rails app.
  theForm.get(0).submit();
}
});

$('.pay_button').click(function(e) {

var theForm = $(this).closest('form');

// Open Checkout with further options: 
handler.open({
  name: 'Fullstack Solutions',
  description: 'Invoice for Services',
  zipCode: false,
  currency: 'aud',
  amount: <%=invoice.total_amount*100%>,
  email: "<%=current_user.email%>"
});
e.preventDefault();
 });

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
handler.close();
});

</script>
```

The key here is that theForm variable needs to be defined only after the click event as there are multiple forms on the page (index of invoices). After the click event theForm is defined by the parent form of the button that was clicked.

This worked fine last night but now theForm is not defined when token function runs.

I am sure this is a simple problem and I am super frustrated as it was working perfectly...

Comment: You might need to define your handler inside `$('.pay_button').click(function(e) {...})` so it has access to `theForm` by lexical scoping.

Comment: seems to have worked with theForm but now the handler.close functionality isn't working properly. After closing the popup the iframe stays in place blocking all website functionality

Comment: right, because now handler is only available inside the `click` handler. How about you move this part inside the function too?

Comment: yup already tried that. Interestingly it works fine for the last invoice listed on the index page but not for the others... some sort of naming conflict maybe?

Comment: You mean after you moved the 'popstate' part inside your 'click' callback function,  iframe stays in place after you close the popup except for the last invoice on the list?

Comment: correct - the last one functions correctly but the others in the loop do not close the iframe on close.

Comment: I think the problem is this `$('.pay_button').click(function(e) {})`. The last time it executes, it binds the listener to your last `.pay_button`, and that gets picked up as the context in the closure. You can either make this into an immediately invoked function expression or use a different id for each invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to define theForm as a global variable in the script (which may be bad practise but it simplified the jQuery significantly). Final code is:

```
<script>

var theForm;
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: $('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'),
image: "<%= image_path "half logo.png"%>",
locale: 'auto',
token: function(token) {
  // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
  // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.

  var token = token.id;
  //Inject the card token in a hidden field.
  theForm.append( $('<input type="hidden" name="stripe_card_token">').val(token) );
  //Submit form to our Rails app.
  theForm.get(0).submit();

}
});

$('.pay_button').click(function(e) {


theForm = $(this).closest('form');

// Open Checkout with further options: 
handler.open({
  name: 'Fullstack Solutions',
  description: 'Invoice for Services',
  zipCode: false,
  currency: 'aud',
  amount: <%=invoice.total_amount*100%>,
  email: "<%=current_user.email%>"
});


e.preventDefault();


}); 
// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
handler.close();
});
```